# Javascript script stopped working and i can't figure out why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade, jsfiddle

Can anyone tell me why this might not be working ? oO It was just a few minutes ago and i have no idea what i did that could have broke it. Basically when i clink one of the menu items it shud fade in that menu assigned text. I put it in a jfiddle so you guys could maybe help me, thanks in advance.

jsfiddle.net/qA8Ur/
i couldn't add the jfiddle link sorry guys

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Hey buddy - you should add some code so we have something to review :)

Comment: should have read own question before posting it here ;)

Comment: "Javascript script stopped working and i can't figure out why" is a statement, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in order to help you... Add jQuery to used Frameworks & Extensions on the left, and fix multiple syntax errors. I strongly recommend you to use proper code formatting and debugging tool (e.g. Chrome Development Tools or Firebug).

**DEMO:** jsfiddle.net/qA8Ur/1/

Comment: I'm new here but, the one you sent me actually works, what did you change? just the jQuery thingie? thanks

Comment: thanks i just noticed what was wrong, i deleted one of the menus and forgot a }) in the end . Thank you so much VisioN